# Linux: single NIC is named eth0/eth1 due to udev and MAC-based rules. Kinda weird

Tags: eth0

I have a motherboard with onboard NIC (single Ethernet NIC in the computer); also USB port is constantly occupied with Wifi dongle.

in my /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, found this:

```
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="6c:f0:49:e8:22:cd", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1e:68:dc:96:52", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Currently, eth0 is detected. If I reboot, it may become eth1 (don't sure if mac will change, I wont reboot this PC today).

```
# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:68:dc:96:52
```

Sometimes, eth0 is not detected and eth1 comes up.
***Why?*** Can it be some BIOS bug with setting onboard MAC when cold-booted improperly?

Currently the ruleset is changed to force name to eth0 (for both macs), should the next reboots reveal if it helps..

Comment: That is **very** odd. It sounds like your MAC address is flipping between two very different values, which is neither random nor bit-flipped. Weird.

Comment: Can you clarify how many NICs the pc has in it? One or two? You say "Onboard NIC, single NIC".

Comment: Can you also explain if you have a wireless card or other network=type adapter? Possibly IRDA?

Comment: @Glen M, fixed: "onboard NIC (single Ethernet NIC in the computer)". USB Wifi device is constantly inserted to port so doubt that it can affect reboots. But..

Comment: What's the MAC address on the USB wifi device? Can you send the output of "ifconfig -a"? What's the MAC address of the USB NIC?